# How to compare two columns( A and B) and if column A value does not exists in column B, add that value to column B in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, compare

I want to compare two columns, A and B, and add values from column A to column B, if the value from column A does not exist in column B.

I have tried the below code block, however I got an error when I try that.

```
for c1 in df['A']:
  for c2 in df['B']:
    if c1!=c2 : 
        df['B'].append(c1)
```

My database looks like below.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Brian | Meg |
| Peter | Stevie |
| Stevie | Chris |

Desired output:

| B |
| --- |
| Meg |
| Stevie |
| Chris |
| Brian |
| Peter |

Comment: whats your error?

Comment: Its hard to comment/answer without seeing a reproducible sample of your data.

Comment: please post ur full code if you can

Comment: Do you need pandas for this? Using pure Python with a set is simpler. If you really need it you can use pandas' "merge" to create a dataframe with NaNs for the missing values and add them to the column "B".

Comment: Yes pandas would work. How to code it tho?

Comment: Edited for a solution in pandas in order to get desired output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
for c1 in df['A']:
    if c1 not in df['B']:
        df['B'].append(c1)
```

should work if i have understand ur  question correctly.
example:

```
df = {
'A' : [1,2,3],
'B' : [1,2,4]
}

for c1 in df['A']:
    if c1 not in df['B']:
        df['B'].append(c1)

print(df)
```

prints:

```
{'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 2, 4, 3]}
```

EDIT:

I have edited it for a solution for DataFrames.

```
dfa = df['A']
dfb = df['B']

dfa = dfa.rename(columns={'A':'B'})

# use concat to merge it

new_df = pd.concat([dfa,dfb])

new_df = new_df.drop_duplicates()
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: It returns a typerror.    TypeError: Series.rename() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'